# Bootstrap: make a dynamic div between navbar-fixed-top and navbar-fixed-bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, alignment

I have a Bootstrap Page with two div's for navigation, one is a navbar-fixed-top and the other is a navbar-fixed-bottom. So, the navbars stick to the top/bottom.

Now I want to declare a div that is exactly the space between the two navbars (xxxxxx in the sketch). Any suggestions on how you would implement this div?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    ..
  </div>
</div>

[DIV FOR THE REST OF THE PAGE]

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container">
    ..
  </div>
</div>
```

.________________________________________________________.
|~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~navbar-fixed-top~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|
|________________________________________________________|
|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|
|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|
|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|
|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|
|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|
|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|
|________________________________________________________|
|~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~navbar-fixed-bottom~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|
|________________________________________________________|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Your Navbars are fixed. You May Add Margin in Top and Bottom of body.

```
<html>    
 <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
              <div class="container">
                ..
              </div>
            </div>


            [DIV FOR THE REST OF THE PAGE]


            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
              <div class="container">
                ..
              </div>
            </div>
        <style>
            body{
                 margin-top: 100px;
                 margin-bottom: 100px;
            }
        </style>
    </body>
</html>
```

Margin top is the height of top nav, and Margin bottom is the height of bottom nav.

Comment: You May Also Add Margin For Body.

Comment: but that is not responsive, is it?

Comment: I think its right, If the navbars have a fixed height. If not you can change using @media() css.

Comment: You Are Welcome.

Comment: but how do I tell the
`<div class="contentarea">
    [DIV FOR THE REST OF THE PAGE]
</div>`
to be as high as the rest of the remaining page. Right now it is only as high as it's content and that is 0px.

Comment: Then Add margin Top For body as.     
body{
         margin-top: 100px;
         margin-bottom: 100px;
    }

Comment: The navbars are within the body, so that doesn't seem right. :/

Comment: I need to know the height of the remaining space, then I would be able to declare it...

Comment: Is the navbars are fixed? If Yes, Then No Problem. You May add Margin for body. Otherwise you can Use JQuery to find the height of the navbars.

Comment: Ok. You are Welcome.